# Simple jQuery Toggle of children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Um, why no worky? Trying to toggle a ul with this:

```
 $("#others").children(".btn").click(function(){
    if ($(this).children("ul").is(":hidden"))
    {
   $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
    } else {
   $(this).children("ul").slideUp();
    }
 });
```

And:

```
<div id="other">
 <div id="galleries">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Galleries >> </a>
  <ul id="select_gallery">
  ...
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="events">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Events >> </a>
  <ul id="select_event">
  ...
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your first div id is other yet your event is bound to #others ?

Comment: "Um, why no worky?" - that's kind of annoying, FYI.

Comment: Sorry, too much coffee. Will try not to sound like a whinning teenage girl next time.

Comment: Here other approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827451/jquery-slidetoggle-one-div-at-a-time-instead-of-all-independently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UL isn't a child of the .btn its a sibling, try using next:

```
$("#other a.btn").click(function(){
    var ul = $(this).next("ul");
    if (ul.is(":hidden")) {
        ul.slideDown();
    } else {
        ul.slideUp();
    }
});
```