# SlideToggle in wordpress - only one open at a time?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle

I really hope someone can help! I've found numerous posts on slideToggle and how to show only one div at a time, but I don't know how to implement it into this menu in the wordpress theme I bought. Here is the theme: http://themes.themegoods.com/rhea_wp (I've hacked the menu so it doesn't do that annoying fade thing (and the music). But see how all the menus stay open when you click them? Below is the code for the menu. Is it possible to edit this code to make it only show one submenu at a time? I'd like the others to close when you click on another main link. Maybe I don't need to use slideToggle? Perhaps slideUp and slideDown? Or something else? I'm new and really need to fix this soon for a client! I appreciate any help!

```
$j.fn.setNav = function(){
$j('#main_menu li ul').css({display: 'none'});

$j( 'ul#main_menu > li:has( ul li.current-menu-item )' ).each(function()
{   
    $j(this).find('ul.sub-menu').css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display:  'block'});
});

$j('ul#main_menu > li:has( ul.sub-menu )').click(function()
{

    var $jsublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');
    $jsublist.slideToggle('fast');

    return false;
});

$j('ul#main_menu > li > ul.sub-menu li ').click(function()
{
    var subURL = $j(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    location.href=subURL;
    return true;
}); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was simply that the theme was using an old version of jQuery - 1.3.2 to be exact. Once I called the newest version, the menu worked with this modification:

```
$j('ul#main_menu > li:has( ul.sub-menu )').click(function () {
var $jsublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');
    $('.visible').slideUp('fast')
    $jsublist.slideToggle('fast').addClass('visible');
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

try .live or .on

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I checked those out, but I'm not sure what to do with them that is different from what slideToggle can do? I feel like maybe I need to use slideUp and slideDown? I found a basic example that did what I needed to do on this forum - but I wasn't sure how to apply it to my menu in particular. Here is the solution I think could work if I knew how to implement it into my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827451/jquery-slidetoggle-one-div-at-a-time-instead-of-all-independently

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be hacking themes for clients without understanding the underlying code, it's only going to come back and haunt you in the future when something breaks or the client wants something new.

That said as a quick hack changing this line:

```
$jsublist.slideToggle('fast');
```

To this, might work:

```
$('ul.sub-menu').slideDown('fast');
$jsublist.slideToggle('fast');
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this right now. As for hacking the theme, I know enough to remove music and take the blur off of links. I'm pretty advanced with CSS and HTML. It's modifying jQuery where things get sticky for me, as I do not have deep knowledge of javascript.

Comment: Oops. I hit enter before I was done. I meant to add that I have a partner who can help me with these types of modifications, but he is sadly on vacation. At any rate, I just tried this and unfortunately it didn't work. Now the dropdowns don't show at all. :/ I really appreciate your help. I'll keep searching...

Comment: @Lindsay Can you post a link to the site and I'll see if I can get it working.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking a look. I'm still developing on my local machine, but if you look at this demo, I have not touched anything about the menu except for remove the blur styles, so this link will show you the exact code I have on mine.  http://themes.themegoods.com/rhea_wp/ When you go to one of the pages, I do want that submenu to remain open when you're on the current page. I just don't want all the menus to be expanded without closing the others. Do you think that will work?