# jQuery toggle allow default href of parent element AND parent element should show child elements (toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to open a link for example "1" (1.html) and afterwards it should show (toggle) all child elements of the site 1 (1-1, 1-2,...). I did a research in google and of course also in stackoverflow.

I only found a similar issue of someone who uses wordpress, which it comes nearly to my wish, but I am not a expert like you guys: http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/jquery-toggle-and-allow-default

```
<div class="col col-md-3">
<nav id="#mobile-nav" class="nav clearfix" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav" id="menu-flag-menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
        <li><a href="1.html">1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="1-1.html">1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="1-2.html">1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="1-3.html">1-3</a></li>         
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="2.html">2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="2-1.html">2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="2-2.html">2-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="2-3.html">2-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="2-4.html">2-4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>           
        <li><a href="#3">3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#3.1">3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3.2">3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My jQuery toggle function:

```
$("#menu-flag-menu li a").click(function(){ 
// close all opened sub menus
$("#menu-flag-menu > li > ul > li > ul  > li > ul").slideUp();
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534162/simple-jquery-toggle-of-children
var ul = $(this).next("ul");
if (ul.is(":hidden")) {
    ul.slideDown();
} 
else {
    ul.slideUp();
} });
```

My CSS:

```
ul#menu-flag-menu > li > ul { display:none; }
```

I hope you can help me, thanks! This is my first question, I don't double post and I try to used my brain, google and stackoverflow, before I ask. :)

I guess the JSfiddle would not help for imagine my demand, but here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/tFh9w/1/

Comment: You are not considering that as soon as you click a link, the page loads and everything starts again. Or are you loading things dynamically but just didn't tell us?

Comment: I guess the first one! I don't think that I load something dynamically. I only use html, css, js and little bit php, but only to cut the page in different parts.

Comment: Ok, if you're only using static HTML files then you need JS to detect what page the browser has opened, and to then trigger the opening of the relevant menu item.

Comment: ok, there I was afraid of... I thought there were a easier solution with jquery possible. A friend of mine suggest via SMS, this should the same suggestion like yours, right?: //ask for the filename:
if 2.html then echo ... else...

Comment: jQuery is JS, it's not too hard to achieve. SMS? Do you mean PHP? Yes that's the correct logic.

Comment: ha ha ha, you are funny. i like! I sent the demand link from stack overflow to a friend of mine and yes, his solution would be php! correct logic ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tFh9w/8/

Because you are using static HTML files, unless you want to make the menu different in each file (I hope you're at least including the menu using SSI), you need JS to detect what page the browser has opened, and to then trigger the opening of the relevant menu item.

First of all let's make it easy and add a `level1` class to the level 1 menu elements.

```
<li class="level1"><a href="1.html">1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1-1.html">1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="1-2.html">1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="1-3.html">1-3</a></li>         
    </ul>
</li>   
<li class="level1"><a href="2.html">2</a>
      etc etc
```

Then we find the last part of the URL, and use jquery to find the anchor who's href matches it. Then we check if it's a parent or child (only works for two levels, but can be adapted for more) and we open the correct menu item.

```
$(function(){
    var hrefs = $.trim(window.location.href).replace(/\/$/, "").split('/');
    var href = hrefs[hrefs.length -1];
    href = '1.html'; // we have to cheat in jsfiddle. remove this line in production
    // href = '1-1.html';
    $('#menu-flag-menu a[href="' + href + '"]').each(function(){
        // what are we opening - the child of this link or the parent?

        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('level1')) $ul = $(this).parent().children('ul');
        else $ul = $(this).closest('ul');

        $ul.slideDown();
    });

});
```

In the example I've had to cheat because  in jsfiddle the href is always going to be `_display`

Comment: hi popnoodles, i will take a deeper look in your code tomorrow. it sounds like a good solution, i will test it in xammp. :)

Comment: Hi popnoodles, wow, fantastic! Your solution is wonderful! I have to study your solution, now. How can I say thank you?